# Automate AI-Platforms model deployment using pipelines on GCP

Tags: tensorflow, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-ai-platform, google-cloud-ai-platform-pipelines

I have some models running in AI-Platforms under GCP which are serving predictions without a problem.
Now I am trying to automate this deployment process using kubernets pipelines so that model version gets updated periodically. I tried to create some pipelines using available samples but non of these are for AI platforms.
The training of the model has been handled by AI-Platform Jobs with following parameters:

- Python: 3.7
- Framework: Tensorflow
- Framework version: 2.1
- ML runtime version: 2.1

Trained model are being created parodically and are being saved in buckets.
How can I automate this deployment process using pipelines.
If there is another alternative approach for this automation, I would like to try it as well.

Comment: No one seems to have an answer for my question. :(

Comment: Did you check the examples here? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/mlops-on-gcp/tree/master/workshops/tfx-caip-tf21

Comment: I implemented this using Cloud Functions that is triggered when bucket gets updated with new model. This was fairly easy to implement and performed quite well.